# SSRS 2012 Excel Rendering Extension Not Honoring Author or Description Document Properties

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234(v=sql.110).aspx#DocumentProperties) link I should be able to assign both the Author and Description fields within an SSRS report and have those export to Excel as document properties.

This works perfectly for PDF and Word but I cannot get this to work for Excel, even though it is a documented feature.

Has anyone come across this before? Any solutions you can share would be appreciated.

[image]